# XAMPP only lets me connect to index.php and not other pages

Tags: php, xampp

I have XAMPP working just fine on one computer. Then I installed it on another and using the same files I have the following issue.

localhost:82 brings up the index.php file (and actually is able to redirect to index3.html as it should). I enter my password there and normally it will then redirect me to localhost:82/home.php (and it does on my other computer) but on this one, it takes about 10 seconds of waiting, then I get a connection err page from chrome and IE. I noticed that this is caused by XAMPP apache server going yellow briefly at this point before returning to green status.

I can't connect to localhost:82/home.php directly either. I get the same error.

I have this at the start of each .php page. Removing it did not solve the problem.

```
<?php 
   session_start();
 //Check to make sure the person is loggedin
   if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true) {
 //if logged in then do nothing
    } else {
 //if not logged int he redirect to the login page
   header("Location: http://localhost:82/index2.php");
   }
?>
```

**It works just fine on my first computer, what is going on here?**

============================

**EDIT: HERE IS THE CODE THAT IS ON MY INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php

//Connect to a database
$host_name  = "localhost";
$database   = "db608008888";
$user_name  = "ABC";
$password   = "123";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);


//Take the values from the html form and assign them to variables
$ID = $_POST['name'];
$userpassword = $_POST['password'];

//If no passsowrd entered then go straight to index.php
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($userpassword);</script>";
if ($userpassword == null) {
  header("Location: http://localhost:82/index3.php");
  die();
}

//Check to see if the password matches the hashes
if (md5($userpassword) === '5b5c45f1b9e444d9e441211cfb325270' 
    or md5($userpassword) === '17434cf0d4ba816cd776ff8b0ec532f1' 
    or md5($userpassword) === '7a94fda2a6e81a1693533e6dc8501b37' 
    or md5($userpassword) === '2d8b2ba14eeb0ac1fe474d468b720771') 
{
//Add the visitor name to our list
  mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `visitor list` (`Visitor Name`) VALUES     ('$ID')") or die("Error in INSERT: ".mysqli_error($connect));


// Start the session so they can access other pages
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
// Redirect them to rest of site
  header("Location: http://localhost:82/home.php");
  die();
 }

else {
  header("Refresh: 0; url=index2.php");
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Wrong Password. .\");</script>";

  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Is there something in the [apache logfile(s)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html), the [php logfile(s)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) and/or the [windows event log](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) that seems to be related to the problem?

Comment: In event viewer I have a lot of these:

Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.18.0, time stamp: 0x5667f02e
Faulting module name: php7ts.dll, version: 7.0.1.0, time stamp: 0x5671ed04
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0001ac04
Faulting process id: 0x7f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d14a9e618e67c3
Faulting application path: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Faulting module path: C:\xampp\php\php7ts.dll
Report Id: a04d87bd-b691-11e5-be9b-d050990c9b8b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: In apache error log this stands out:

[ssl:warn] [pid 740:tid 372] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Do you use the "vanilla" XAMPP installation or did you add/replace e.g. .dlls or something similar?

Comment: Vanilla, but I changed the directory to the folder where my files are. However this did not cause issues on my other computer and the index.php still loads so I don't think that is an issue.

Comment: PHP scripts shouldn't™ be able to cause an access violation (0xc0000005) that kills the apache. I would: a) check the hdd b) run a memtest from (almost) any linux cd c) install xampp anew from scratch

Comment: I did try the fresh install with no avail.

Comment: Is one of the scripts that cause the access violation small enough, so you can [add it to your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34689890/edit)? Maybe it's one of the extension modules and we can identify the function that isn't working. Access violation -> can be anything; together with memory leaks the most dreadful errors :-/

Comment: oh, and btw: Both machines have the same os (and same patch level) and same™ setup?

Comment: Same OS. Not sure about the others

Comment: @VolkerK take a look at my update, posted the code from index.php but like I said. I don't think it's the code that is the problem.

Now, once difference is that I commented out the sql code because I didn't want to setup a new db on this computer.

Comment: The index.php is the one working, isn't it? Is one of the scripts _that cause the access violation_ small enough, so you can add it to your question text? Or alternatively does the apache also crash if you put only `<?php echo 'hi there.'` in home.php?

Comment: All the php script used on any page is listed above.

index.php doesn't crash it. It redirects me to index3.php which has no php in it. Once I login index.php runs that code and verifies my login. Then it tries to redirect me to home.php and that is where xampp dies and results in a connection error in the browser.

Comment: Ok, then I'm only interested in home.php or more precisely if there's a function/method call to another extension module in it that might crash. If you replace home.php by `<php phpinfo(); ?>`, it doesn't crash, right?

Answer (score 0):

Open apache’s configuration file using your favorite text editor. The configuration file generally locates at:

```
{apache_dir}/conf/httpd.conf
```

If you are using XAMPP or WAMP package then you will find the file at:

```
{xampp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
{wamp_dir}/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Search for the following string:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and uncomment it (remove the ‘#’ sign).
Now search for another string AllowOverride None and replace it by AllowOverride All

Restart Apache !

Done

Comment: #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so was already uncommented.

Override All now caused my apache server to not start. Fails everytime I click start.

Comment: unfortuantely this did not change anything for me

Comment: What error? I used localhost to get to the index.php then to index3.php and when I entered the login info the XAMPP lost connection briefly and I couldn't get past it the login page.

Comment: Sorry, the override all was not causing the crash. But changing that to All doesn't solve my problem

Comment: In event viewer I have a lot of these: Faulting application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.18.0, time stamp: 0x5667f02e Faulting module name: php7ts.dll, version: 7.0.1.0, time stamp: 0x5671ed04 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0001ac04 Faulting process id: 0x7f8 Faulting application start time: 0x01d14a9e618e67c3 Faulting application path: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe Faulting module path: C:\xampp\php\php7ts.dll Report Id: a04d87bd-b691-11e5-be9b-d050990c9b8b Faulting package full name: Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: In apache error log this stands out: [ssl:warn] [pid 740:tid 372] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name